# Gmap.js checkGeoFence method not returning anything

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I am having some trouble using checkGeoFence from the Google Maps Javascript Library. I was hoping someone who have used before could help me. I am just trying to determine if a point is between a polygon.
Here is my code:
http://jsbin.com/sexihiba/1/edit

The method checkGeofence it's not working correctly. It's not returning anythig.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: the 3rd argument is expected to be a polygon, not a path

Comment: Thanks man! That was the problem!