# Gmaps checkGeofence function returning true for all coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geofencing

I am trying to create a geofence in [Gmaps](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) and then load multiple markers on to the map but while doing so I check if the marker is within the boundary of geofence using `checkGeofence()`. if it is then I add it in the map and if it is not I want to ignore it and just display a message that the marker is not within the boundary.

The problem is when I try to do this using the following code:

```
var poi_coordinates = [[32.27, 77.19],[32.25, 77.22] , [32.23, 77.21], [32.24, 77.17],[26.61,77.19]]

var lattitude = 32.25; //28.6339;
var longitude = 77.19; //77.2200;

//creating map
var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: 32.25,
    lng: 77.19,
    zoom:10
});

//creating geofence
circle = map.drawCircle({
    lat: lattitude,
    lng: longitude,
    strokeColor: '#fff',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: 'rgba(75,255,0,0.2)',
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    radius: 4000,
    editable: true,
});

//Plotting Main Coordinates
map.addMarker({
    lat: lattitude,
    lng: longitude,
    draggable: true,
    fences: [circle],
    outside: function (marker, fence) {
        alert('This marker has been moved outside of its fence');
    }
});

//Plotting extra coordinates
for (var a = 0; a < poi_coordinates.length; a++) {
    if (map.checkGeofence(poi_coordinates[a][0], poi_coordinates[a][1], circle)) {

        //Code work properly as it should if I add this alert line
        //alert(map.checkGeofence(poi_coordinates[a][0], poi_coordinates[a][1], circle))

        map.addMarker({
            lat: poi_coordinates[a][0],
            lng: poi_coordinates[a][1],
            draggable: true,
            fences: [circle],
            outside: function (marker, fence) {
                alert('This marker has been moved outside of its fence');
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        alert(poi_coordinates[a][0] + "," + poi_coordinates[a][1] + ' is out of the 4 Km fence')
    }
}
```

It only works if I have added the `alert` command even when I am adding the marker on the map. If I don't add the `alert` command there I dont know what happens exactly but all the markers gets added into the map.

Please help. Here is the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e52792j5/16/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gmap.js checkGeoFence method not returning anything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316636/gmap-js-checkgeofence-method-not-returning-anything) (a circle is not a google.maps.Polygon)

Comment: Its not that problem I have already checked that out. 
 
In that the function was not returning any value but in my case it does return true or false just not always the way I want it to.